# How to remove certain columns in multiple data frames in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

lets say I have many data frames with different names of almost similar columns.  How do I manipulate the columns of individual data frames using loops (or any other way)?  For example, I want to remove the first column of all data frames at once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have several data.frames `dat1`, `dat2`, `dat3`, etc.  Instead of working with individual datasets, place them in a `list` and do the processing.  After the removal of first column, if you still need the original `data.frame` object to reflect the change (not advised as you can do all the analysis within the list itself), use `list2env`.

```
 lst <- mget(ls(pattern='^dat\\d+'))
 list2env(lapply(lst,`[`,-1), envir=.GlobalEnv)

 dat1
```

If you have different dataset names `D1`, `C1`, `datC`, `newDat` etc with no clear common patterns (not clear from the question), then you could still create a list manually (extreme cases)

```
 lst1 <- list(D1=D1, C1=C1, datc=datC, newDat=newDat)
```

and do the `list2env(lapply(...`

Or read all the files (if all the files are in the working directory) directly into a list and process it.

```
 files <- list.files() #if you want to read all the files in working directory
 lst2 <- lapply(files, function(x) read.table(x, header=TRUE))
 lapply(lst2,`[`,-1)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
dat1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:40, 5*3, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
dat2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(20, 3*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=3))
dat3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(80, 2*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=2))
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.  One question about `pattern`, what if the data frame is `df_2014_JAN`,`df_2013_FEB`, etc.?

Comment: @Yusri You can set the pattern as `ls(pattern='^df\\_\\d+\\_[A-Z]+')`