# Removing columns from the list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, lapply

I have list of CSV files which looks like the dataframe I created below:

```
a<-data.frame(A=c("Boston","Boston","Boston","Boston","Boston"), 
              pred_1=c(4,3,32,2,3), pred_2=c(5,3,2,6,22), pred_3=c(3,2,7,1,23), 
              pred_4=c(8,9,2,6,21), pred_5=c(4,3,32,2,3), pred_6=c(5,3,2,6,22), 
              pred_7=c(3,2,7,1,23),pred_8=c(8,9,2,6,21), pred_9=c(4,3,32,2,3),
              pred_10=c(5,3,2,6,22),pred_11=c(3,2,7,1,23),pred_12=c(8,9,2,6,21))

b<-data.frame(A=c("Hartford","Hartford","Hartford","Hartford","Hartford"),
              pred_1=c(3,6,6,2,5), pred_2=c(2,7,8,4,23),pred_3=c(1,4,7,3,22),
              pred_4=c(9,2,1,3,25),pred_5=c(3,6,6,2,5), pred_6=c(2,7,8,4,23),
              pred_7=c(1,4,7,3,22),pred_8=c(9,2,1,3,25),pred_9=c(3,6,6,2,5), 
              pred_10=c(2,7,8,4,23),pred_11=c(1,4,7,3,22),pred_12=c(9,2,1,3,25))
```

`df_list` is the list of dataframes.

```
df_list<-list(a,b)
```

I need to create the dataframes on days basis for instance, day1, day2, day3, day4, and so on.

My requirement here is that, for example, day9 dataframe should not contain columns from pred_1 to pred_8 but contain columns from pred_9 to pred_12; similarly for days11 dataframe should contain columns from pred_11 to pred_12 but should not contain column from pred_1 to pred_10.

I have written code below for creating individual dataframe which is not working as required.

```
# m stores all the csv files
m <- list.files(pattern=".csv",ignore.case=TRUE, all.files = TRUE) 

for(iter in 1:length(m)){

  print(m[iter])
  my_csv=read.csv(m[iter])
  i1 <- 1:12
  i<-1:12

  for(i in seq_along(i1)) {

    print(i)
    assign(paste0("days", i),
          value = my_csv[, setdiff(names(my_csv),
                                  c("A",
                                    grep(paste("_", 1:i1[i],collapse="|", sep=""),
                                         colnames(my_csv), value = TRUE)))])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27399814/how-to-remove-certain-columns-in-multiple-data-frames-in-r)</sup>

```
lapply(mylist,`[`,-2)
```

to remove the second column from a list of dataframes.

In my `for` loop every time I assign this to `mylist` so in the next step the next column will be removed.

```
day1 <- df_list #day1 has all of the columns
mylist <- df_list #make a new list to avoid altering original list

for (i in 2:12) {

 x <- paste0("day",i) 
 assign(x,lapply(mylist,`[`,-2)) 
 mylist <-lapply(mylist,`[`,-2)

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have formed a data frame from `a` and `b` first, and then used the following loop to generate desired output.

```
> df <- rbind(a,b)
> df
          A pred_1 pred_2 pred_3 pred_4 pred_5 pred_6 pred_7 pred_8 pred_9 pred_10 pred_11 pred_12
1    Boston      4      5      3      8      4      5      3      8      4       5       3       8
2    Boston      3      3      2      9      3      3      2      9      3       3       2       9
3    Boston     32      2      7      2     32      2      7      2     32       2       7       2
4    Boston      2      6      1      6      2      6      1      6      2       6       1       6
5    Boston      3     22     23     21      3     22     23     21      3      22      23      21
6  Hartford      3      2      1      9      3      2      1      9      3       2       1       9
7  Hartford      6      7      4      2      6      7      4      2      6       7       4       2
8  Hartford      6      8      7      1      6      8      7      1      6       8       7       1
9  Hartford      2      4      3      3      2      4      3      3      2       4       3       3
10 Hartford      5     23     22     25      5     23     22     25      5      23      22      25

> for(i in 2:ncol(df)) {
+     
+     x <- paste0("Day", i-1)
+     assign(x, cbind(df[1], df[(i):(ncol(df))]))
+     
+ }

> Day4
          A pred_4 pred_5 pred_6 pred_7 pred_8 pred_9 pred_10 pred_11 pred_12
1    Boston      8      4      5      3      8      4       5       3       8
2    Boston      9      3      3      2      9      3       3       2       9
3    Boston      2     32      2      7      2     32       2       7       2
4    Boston      6      2      6      1      6      2       6       1       6
5    Boston     21      3     22     23     21      3      22      23      21
6  Hartford      9      3      2      1      9      3       2       1       9
7  Hartford      2      6      7      4      2      6       7       4       2
8  Hartford      1      6      8      7      1      6       8       7       1
9  Hartford      3      2      4      3      3      2       4       3       3
10 Hartford     25      5     23     22     25      5      23      22      25
```

Comment: original csv's doesn't have same columns. For simplicity, I have taken same columns in this example.

Comment: The other answer provided by @Masoud works in that case.  You can use `max(ncol)` to determine the length of your loop as follows:

`for(i in 2:max(ncol(df_list[[1]]), ncol(df_list[[2]]))) {
  
  x <- paste0("Day", i-1)
  assign(x,lapply(df_list,'[', -2))
  df_list <- lapply(df_list,`[`,-2)
  
}`