# How to drop column(s) from multiple data frames (number can vary) using loops in R

Tags: r

Assume there are multiple `data.frame`s `Sales_1`, `Sales_2`, ..., `Sales_max` where `_max` can be dynamic...

all these data sets have some common columns like `"ID"` which I need to drop!!

Can this be done using a for loop in R?

maybe something like this

```r
for(i in 1:max){
Sales_**i**$ID=NULL #basically I am looking to resolve the variable as data frame name while using the loop
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove certain columns in multiple data frames in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27399814/how-to-remove-certain-columns-in-multiple-data-frames-in-r)

Answer (score 2):

If you have all `data.frames` in a `list`. Then you can use `lapply`, regardless of the datafram name:

```
myNames <- c("john", "fred", "steph","joe", "val")
sales   <- c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 2000)

# Start with some example data:
mynrow <- 6
Sales_1 <- data.frame(ID=1:mynrow, seller=sample(myNames, mynrow, TRUE), amount = sample(sales, mynrow, TRUE))
Sales_2 <- data.frame(ID=1:mynrow, seller=sample(myNames, mynrow, TRUE), amount = sample(sales, mynrow, TRUE))
Sales_3 <- data.frame(ID=1:mynrow, seller=sample(myNames, mynrow, TRUE), amount = sample(sales, mynrow, TRUE))

Sales <- list(Sales_1, Sales_2, Sales_3)

lapply(Sales, function(x) x[-1])
```

Comment: Absolutely the right way to go about this in my humble opinion. Working with separate datasets like `Sales_1` - `Sales_(n)` makes for complicated code later.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
# Start with some example data:
Sales_1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), name=c("john", "fred", "steph"))
Sales_2 <- data.frame(id=c(4,2,1), name=c("joe", "val", "kerry"))
Sales_3 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), name=c("jane", "aaron", "don"))


numberOfSalesDataframes <- 3 # Set this to the number of Sales dataframes you have


for (i in 1:numberOfSalesDataframes) {

  # These two lines of code will remove column "id"
  command <- paste0("Sales_", i, "$id", "  <- NULL")
  eval(parse(text=command))

  # Copy the two lines of code from above to remove another column, and so on..
  # command <- paste0("Sales_", i, "$another_column_you_want_to_remove", "  <- NULL")
  # eval(parse(text=command))

}


Sales_1
Sales_2
Sales_3
```

Comment: namin object `max` is a very bad practice

Comment: @PoGibas great point. Edited and fixed

Comment: man this worked ... thanks a lot .. you are a savior I was searching for a long time for this solution...

Comment: @RishikeshBayya no problems. Please accept the answer so the question does not clog up the unanswered section

Answer (score -1):

You can use `eval` and `substitute` as follows

```r
Sales_1 <- data.frame(id = 1:3, other_stuff = letters[1:3])
Sales_2 <- data.frame(id = 4:6, other_stuff = letters[4:6])
Sales_3 <- data.frame(id=  7:9, other_stuff = letters[7:9])

dfs <- sapply(ls()[grepl("^Sales\\_\\d+$", ls())], as.symbol)
for(sym in dfs)
  eval(substitute(x$id <- NULL, list(x = sym)))

Sales_1
#R   other_stuff
#R 1           a
#R 2           b
#R 3           c
Sales_2
#R   other_stuff
#R 1           d
#R 2           e
#R 3           f
Sales_3
#R   other_stuff
#R 1           g
#R 2           h
#R 3           i
```