# Removing column/s from multiple data-frames

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have multiple data.frames of same columns but in a different order. I want to remove a column from all data frames at once. For example, say columns named "Group 1" and "Group 2" are present.
I tried this but failed.

```
remover<-function(input){

  input<-input[,-c("Group 1","Group 2")]

  return(input)

}
```

Also, I saw this link ([How to remove certain columns in multiple data frames in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27399814/how-to-remove-certain-columns-in-multiple-data-frames-in-r)) and don't want to use lists.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it's not very wise to use variable names with whitespace. Use points instead, like `"Group.1"`.

Second, while `c("Group 1","Group 2")` works, `-c("Group 1","Group 2")` won't, because you're attempting to do arithmetics with characters: `- "Group.1"` doesn't make much sense, does it?

So we can use `%in%` which is kind of a matching operator together with `which()` which gives the indices of the elements.

```
remover <- function(input) {
  input <- input[, -which(names(input) %in% c("Group.1", "Group.2"))]
  return(input)
}

x1 <- remover(df1)
> x1
  X1 X2
1  4 10
2  5 11
3  6 12
```

There's another option to achieve the negation of the colnames instead of `-`. We can use `!`.

```
remover2 <- function(input) {
  input <- input[, which(!names(input) %in% c("Group.1", "Group.2"))]
  return(input)
}
```

There might be a slight speed advantage using `!`.

```
Unit: microseconds
          expr    min     lq     mean median     uq       max neval cld
  remover(df1) 26.789 28.065 30.27720 28.321 28.831 18419.152 1e+05   a
 remover2(df1) 26.534 27.810 30.09483 28.065 28.576  6056.713 1e+05   a

> all.equal(x1, x2)
[1] TRUE
```

*Data:*

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, 
                         3, 4, 
                         dimnames=list(NULL, c("Group.1", "X1", 
                                               "Group.2", "X2"))))
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. (Though I had asked to remove; I included "-" in front of "which"). Also, these are just dummy values. my intended column names don't have whitespace. Thank you for the tip though.